# Dojo Place Button Under TabContainer

Tags: dojo

I have the following code inside a `div` element:

```
<div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 100%;" doLayout=”false”>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Basic" data-dojo-props="selected:true" style="display: block">
      <div class="layer-selects">
        <div class="layer-selects row">
            <span class="layer-selects first-col">
              <label for="selectService">${nls.service}:</label>
            </span>
          <span class="layer-selects second-col">
              <select id="selectService"
                      name="selectService"
                      data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
                      data-dojo-attach-point="selectService"
                      data-dojo-attach-event="onChange:onSelectServiceChange">
              </select>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="layer-selects row">
            <span class="layer-selects first-col">
              <label for="selectLayer">${nls.layer}:</label>
            </span>
          <span class="layer-selects second-col">
              <select id="selectLayer"
                      name="selectLayer"
                      data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
                      data-dojo-attach-point="selectLayer"
                      data-dojo-attach-event="onChange:onSelectLayerChange">
              </select>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <span class="layer-selects first-col">
            <label for="searchTerm">${nls.searchTerm}: </label>
          </span>
        <span>
            <input id="searchTerm" type="text"
                   data-dojo-attach-point="searchTermInput"
                   data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                   name="searchTerm"
                   required="true"/>
          </span>
        <span class="layer-selects second-col">
            <select id="selectField"
                    name="selectField"
                    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
                    data-dojo-attach-point="selectField">
            </select>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">${nls.searchButton}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot get the `button` to display under the `TabContainer`.  It is being placed behind the `TabContainer` component at the top of the parent `div`.

How can I place the `button` and any other elements under the `TabContainer`?  The `TabContainer` height needs to be dynamic.  I've tried applying `display: block` styling to the container as well as the `ContentPane`, but this made no difference.  If I set the `height` of the `TabContainer` to a value larger than the `TabContainer`, the button is pushed to the bottom of it.

Comment: have you tried to set a minimum height of your TabContainer , or this doesn't swet you

Comment: @BooBerr'ita that only works if TabContainer content doesn't grow, but I need this to be dynamic.